# Apple tv audio to stop

Tags: tvos

I am using AVPlayer for playing video url coming from server in TVOS SDK . For getting meta data of video I swipe down in video player screen . In metadata screen there are two buttons Info and Audio out of them click on Info button subtitles. After that clicking on Menu button of Apple TV remote I quit the player screen but audio is still playing in the background .

Comment: Are you referring to returning to the Home Screen, or dismissing the player info?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the appropriate `AVAudioSession` for your application and stop all audio in your `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidDisappear`, or  `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

[**AVAudioSession Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)